# What is the cleanest way to extend this design for tree-rewriting?

Tags: c++, refactoring, tree, url-rewriting

I have a tree of objects, where each object has a `std::vector` of pointers to its children. The class of the object has a `rewrite()` method that is recursively applied to alter the object and its children, typically with the following transformations, where `[N]` is the object being rewritten and `(M)` is the element that `rewrite()` returns:

```
                 (A)
 [A]             / \               [A]
 / \     -->    B   X               |    -->    (B)
B   C                \              B
                      C
```

What's the cleanest way of extending this setup to allow transformations like this?

```
    A             X
    |            / \
   [B]   -->    C   A
    |               |
    C              (Y)
```

That is, those that re-root the tree, move an element, insert a new element, and return the inserted element. I'm having a hard time coming up with something nice that also involves minimal refactoring. Thoughts?

Comment: How can a method return Y if A has a pointer to it? Do you mean that the method returns a copy of Y, or that it returns by reference? And must there be any other link to the tree (e.g. a pointer somewhere that points to the root)?

Comment: The elements are returned by pointer (or rather `shared_ptr`). To start rewriting, `rewrite()` is called on the root element of the tree. As it is, `root->rewrite()` returns `root`, but it will need to return the *new* root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, for speed, you'll need a "back-pointer" from each child node to its parent node.  This way you can follow the chain of parent pointers given a pointer to any node all the way to the root, if that's what you need (I'm not sure how else you planned to find the root given just a pointer to an inner node, without backpointers?).  Of course, you'll need to adjust the back pointer, as well as the "children" `std::vector`, whenever you rearrange the tree -- an unfortunate consequence of the slight duplication of information (no more than, say, a doubly linked list presents;-), but a small price to pay for the ease and speed of such bidirectional navigation.

Comment: I solved it by passing a reference to the root pointer as a parameter to `rewrite()`. Rewrites can now alter the root however they please. Thanks for the tip, anyway: it put me on the right track.